# In Google Colab is there a programing way to check which runtime like gpu or tpu environment I am connected to?

Tags: gpu, runtime, google-colaboratory, tpu

In Google Colab, is there a programing way to check which runtime like gpu or tpu environment I am connected to?

for example, I can check that it's under tpu runtime using below code. But what's 'gpu' runtime?

import os

tpu_good_to_go = "COLAB_TPU_ADDR" in os.environ

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```py
import os

if int(os.environ["COLAB_GPU"]) > 0:
  print("a GPU is connected.")
elif "COLAB_TPU_ADDR" in os.environ and os.environ["COLAB_TPU_ADDR"]:
  print("A TPU is connected.")
else:
  print("No accelerator is connected.")
```

You can also organize your code to work on both GPU/TPU using [tf.distribute.Strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy) like this:

```py
# Detect hardware, return appropriate distribution strategy
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection
except ValueError:
    tpu = None

if tpu:
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
else:
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() # works on GPU and multi-GPU

print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following response provide the details if your use-case works other than using os package.

Default mode in colab, where you see General CPU (eg. /device:CPU:0) is used as provided info by the following command in Colab.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Output:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 14923719279742952081]
```

You change the runtime to GPU mode, see the GPU details using TF by the following command in Colab.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Output:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 8024997777994502130, name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 11344216064
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
   links {
   }
 }
 incarnation: 8757379433989904022
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7"]
```